# "android:" prefix in styles and themes

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-appcompat

Assume i want to change a background color for my button and my theme is AppCompat.

I know that in Android >= 21 (lollipop) i should use `android:colorButtonNormal`
and pre-lollipop i should just use `colorButtonNormal`.

But if i use AppCompat 27.0.0 for example, then the minimum supported API level should be 4.0 (API 14) according to the android developer website: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html

does this mean that i can use `android:colorButtonNormal` for all versions of android above API 14 (including lollipop)? or should i still use two different versions of the styles?

I personally think that i should include both but i want some confirmation on this

Comment: `... and pre-lollipop i should just use colorButtonNormal` are you sure about this?!

Comment: yes i'm sure. the prefix namespace is used for versions of Android that include the style in the platform. Without the prefix is for older versions that read the style from the Support library

Comment: Because i develop for a target 18. And I always prefix `android:` to the system colors. I don't have to use the prefix only when I use **my own** colors.

Comment: do you assign the color with the colorButtonNormal attribute? because that one was introduced in lollipop. If you just used background to assign a color  for example, its not necessairy

Comment: No. Is it only **that** color (or ones introduced in later OS versions than 18) we're talking about? If so, you may be correct.

Comment: you only have to care about prefixes if you use attributes introduced in a newer version, just like colorButtonNormal. I don't want to change the color with background because i still want to use the looks of the appCompat button and other controls will automatically be altered too if i use colorButtonNormal

Comment: also it's not about colors here i'm talking about. it's about the colorButtonNormal style attribute (you can look it up)

Comment: But colors is an example of this. Its possible to use platform colors with the prefix. But if you specify colors from your app you don't use the prefix. Support libraries are also part of your app thus you shouldn't use prefixes for attributes. Get it?